# How to give version to a module loaded on HPC

Tags: linux

I am very new to linux environment and I have an issue with loading a module in linux. The problem is I am trying to point an already loaded module to the one present in my local directory. For this I have changed all the path that would point the module to my local directory and also updated the `MODULEPATH` with my local directory path.

This is the command I am using for changing the `MODULEPATH`

```
export MODULEPATH=~/local/directory:${MODULEPATH}
```

Though the question I have is completely different, how to give a version number to my module?

I have a moudle file which looks like this -

```
#%Module

proc ModulesHelp { } {
    puts stderr "Sets up users' environment to use XXXX. XXXX is the ..\n.. It is a piece of middleware developed by XXXX to \nhelp track XXX usage. \n\nIf you encounter any problems while linking or while executing aprun, please unload this module."
  }

conflict totalview

setenv XXXX_SELECT_ON 0
setenv XXXX_SELECT_USERS kagrawa1
setenv XXXX_SELECT_OFF_USERS "" 
setenv XXXX_VERBOSE 0

setenv XXXX_ON 1
setenv XXXX_PATH /d/home/kpilagr/

prepend-path PATH           /nics/d/home/kagrawa1/altd/bin
```

Comment: its a software which keeps the track of libraries that are used on a hpc for all the apps (thrid party/vendor or owned). I other words to track library usage on a HPC. So this module is already up and working in production. I need to make some enhancement in this module for that I need to install a local copy of this in my directory and point it running production to local (via MODULEPATH change).

Comment: Are you sure you are using python? That `ModulesHelp` proc looks more like `tcl` ...

Comment: apologies my mistake, Its not in python